# Learning names of spammers

Tags: string, algorithm, machine-learning, similarity, feature-engineering

Currently, some spam waves, especially when sport events happen, are flooding the internet.

As I strongly doubt that the usernames of the spammers aren't computer generated, I thought it might be interesting to try learning spammer names programatically somehow.

A user name should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers, `_` or `-`.

A sample list of names would be

```
riazsports0171
maya34444
thelmaeatons
tigran777
newlive100
darbeshbaba
litondina10
nithuhasan
newlive100
bankuali
lldztwydni554
monomala505
nasiruddin1500
lldztwydni554
ariful3032
nazmulhasan
```

I do only have a fairly basic knowledge of algorithms (from university). My question is, which machine learning algorithms and/or string metrics I could use for predicting if an arbitary username is probably a spammer or not.
I thought about using cosine string similaritz, because its fairly simple.

Comment: You would need to have a dataset of names where each name is labelled as belonging to a spammer or not.

Comment: by your logic, "user3001" is a probable spammer

Comment: what other information you have ?! the content or only these names ?! I agree the string similarity is the easiest and fairly the best option !

Comment: Scraping the contents would be very tedious, I would prefer only having to deal with names. I got far more of these spammer usernames, I just wanted to provide an example how it looks like. Btw I'm not a spammer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. But I don't think *string similarity* algorithms are the best solution.

I'd try to extract features from the names, and use a **[classification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification)**. [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) usually provides very good results comparing to other classification algorithms, but there are other algorithms as well (For example: [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), [Decision Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning), [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm)) each with its advantages and disadvantages.

The tricky part will be to **extract the features**. You should be creative. Some options are: number of digits, number of consecutive letters, number of consecutive consonant, usage of capitalization, correct usage of capitalization, is matching a certain regex, ... (You could also use other features not from the string, such as number of msgs sent by this user to you, ....)

Next, you need to **create a training set**. This training set will contain both spammers and non-spammers user names, which are manually labeled for spammers or non-spammers.

Feed the training set to your algorithm of choice, and it will **create a classifier**, which you will be able to use to predict if new users are spammers or not.

You can **evaluate effectiveness** of each algorithm by using [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) on your data.

Comment: That should give me some good points to start from, thank you very much!